# How to convert file to base64 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, base64

**UPD** TypeScript version is also available in answers

Now I'm getting File object by this line:

```
file = document.querySelector('#files > input[type="file"]').files[0]
```

I need to send this file via json in base 64. What should I do to convert it to base64 string?

Answer (score 438, accepted):

**Modern ES6 way** (async/await)

```
const toBase64 = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = reject;
});

async function Main() {
   const file = document.querySelector('#myfile').files[0];
   console.log(await toBase64(file));
}

Main();
```

UPD:

If you want to catch errors

```
async function Main() {
   const file = document.querySelector('#myfile').files[0];
   try {
      const result = await toBase64(file);
      return result
   } catch(error) {
      console.error(error);
      return;
   }
   //...
}
```

Comment: This code is incorrect. If you `await` a function that returns a rejected Promise, you won't get an Error returned by the call; it will be thrown and you will need to catch it.

Comment: I actually tried this snippet trying to convert a image on a <input type='file' /> and got an error. : Users.js:41 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

Comment: thanks one more question how can I set the content type only image

Comment: @SHAHEEREZ You need to specify content type in an form input, not in a code. `<input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg">`

Answer (score 451):

Try the solution using the `FileReader` [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader):

```
function getBase64(file) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   reader.onload = function () {
     console.log(reader.result);
   };
   reader.onerror = function (error) {
     console.log('Error: ', error);
   };
}

var file = document.querySelector('#files > input[type="file"]').files[0];
getBase64(file); // prints the base64 string
```

Notice that `.files[0]` is a `File` type, which is a sublcass of `Blob`. Thus it can be used with `FileReader`.
See the complete working [example](http://jsbin.com/piqiqecuxo/1/edit?js,console,output).

Comment: read more about FileReader API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader and browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader

Comment: I tried to use `return reader.result` from the `getBase64()` function (rather than using `console.log(reader.result)`) because i want to capture the base64 as a variable (and then send it to Google Apps Script).  I called the function with: `var my_file_as_base64 = getBase64(file)` and then tried to print to console with `console.log(my_file_as_base64 )` and just got `undefined`.  How can I properly assign the base64 to a variable?

Comment: I made a question out of the above comment if anyone can answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47195119/how-to-capture-filereader-base64-as-variable

Comment: I need to open this Base64 file in browser with the same file name, i am opening it using window.open(url, '_blank') which is working fine, how can i give file name to that ? please help.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is not explained very well on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL

Answer (score 163):

If you're after a promise-based solution, this is @Dmitri's code adapted for that:

```
function getBase64(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
  });
}

var file = document.querySelector('#files > input[type="file"]').files[0];
getBase64(file).then(
  data => console.log(data)
);
```

Comment: I need to open this Base64 file in browser with the same file name, i am opening it using window.open(url, '_blank') which is working fine, how can i give file name to that ? please help.

Answer (score 104):

Building up on Dmitri Pavlutin and joshua.paling answers, here's an extended version that extracts the base64 content (removes the metadata at the beginning) and also ensures [padding is done correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080988/).

```
function getBase64(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => {
      let encoded = reader.result.toString().replace(/^data:(.*,)?/, '');
      if ((encoded.length % 4) > 0) {
        encoded += '='.repeat(4 - (encoded.length % 4));
      }
      resolve(encoded);
    };
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: Chrome 69, the first replace is to catch empty file, second replace is missing comma - encoded = reader.result.replace("data:", "").replace(/^.*;base64,/, "");

Comment: My word, I did miss that coma indeed. What is incredible is that it didn't seem to bother my backend at all, I was still able to upload excel files successfully o_O. I've fixed the regex to take your empty file use case into account as well. Thanks.

Comment: I've got an even easier version : `resolve(reader.result.replace(/^.*,/, ''));`. Since coma `,` is outside base64 alphabet we can strip anything that comes up until and including the coma. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13195218/1935128

Comment: Ok thanks for the heads up, although according to the regex I wrote here (I'd need to experiment again to be sure), there may just be `data:`, without any comma, so I'll keep that first part as is. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @ArnaudP Typescript error: Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'string | ArrayBuffer'.

Comment: @RomelGomez yes this code is `js` so there is no compiler to bother you about types. In my `ts` code however, I did add `.toString()` before `.replace(...)`. Not sure it is actually necessary, but I'll update my answer just in case. Thx.

Comment: this saved me tons of trouble thank you so much

Answer (score 26):

TypeScript version

```
const file2Base64 = (file:File):Promise<string> => {
    return new Promise<string> ((resolve,reject)=> {
         const reader = new FileReader();
         reader.readAsDataURL(file);
         reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result?.toString() || '');
         reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
     })
    }
```

Comment: reader.result can possibly be null and will through a typescript error. This code handles that case:

`reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result ? reader.result.toString() : '')`

Comment: To prevent `Object is possibly 'null'` error you can use optional chaining operator like this `reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result?.toString() || '');`

Comment: Thank you, I updated the code :)

Answer (score 17):

JavaScript [btoa()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_btoa.asp) function can be used to convert data into base64 encoded string

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <label for="filePicker">Choose or drag a file:</label><br>
        <input type="file" id="filePicker">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <h1>Base64 encoded version</h1>
        <textarea id="base64textarea" 
                  placeholder="Base64 will appear here" 
                  cols="50" rows="15"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
var handleFileSelect = function(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;
    var file = files[0];

    if (files && file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(readerEvt) {
            var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
            document.getElementById("base64textarea").value = btoa(binaryString);
        };

        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    }
};

if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    document.getElementById('filePicker')
            .addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
} else {
    alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
}
```

Comment: btoa works only with string. How to use it with file?

Comment: you will have to read file first and then pass it to this function.. Something like http://jsfiddle.net/eliseosoto/JHQnk/

Comment: @PranavManiar Your fiddle no longer works. Can you update the link?

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me

Comment: Just update the value by ...value = btoa(binaryString) to ...value = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + btoa(binaryString). And point to type which written as jpeg. You may check filetype from file.type.

Answer (score 10):

Here are a couple functions I wrote to get a file in a json format which can be passed around easily:

```
    //takes an array of JavaScript File objects
    function getFiles(files) {
        return Promise.all(files.map(getFile));
    }

    //take a single JavaScript File object
    function getFile(file) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            reader.onerror = () => { reader.abort(); reject(new Error("Error parsing file"));}
            reader.onload = function () {

                //This will result in an array that will be recognized by C#.NET WebApi as a byte[]
                let bytes = Array.from(new Uint8Array(this.result));

                //if you want the base64encoded file you would use the below line:
                let base64StringFile = btoa(bytes.map((item) => String.fromCharCode(item)).join(""));

                //Resolve the promise with your custom file structure
                resolve({ 
                    bytes,
                    base64StringFile,
                    fileName: file.name, 
                    fileType: file.type
                });
            }
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        });
    }

    //using the functions with your file:

    file = document.querySelector('#files > input[type="file"]').files[0]
    getFile(file).then((customJsonFile) => {
         //customJsonFile is your newly constructed file.
         console.log(customJsonFile);
    });

    //if you are in an environment where async/await is supported

    files = document.querySelector('#files > input[type="file"]').files
    let customJsonFiles = await getFiles(files);
    //customJsonFiles is an array of your custom files
    console.log(customJsonFiles);
```

Comment: Promise all, based in a array.map works great! At least for me.

Answer (score 6):

```
const fileInput = document.querySelector('input');

fileInput.addEventListener('change', (e) => {

// get a reference to the file
const file = e.target.files[0];

// encode the file using the FileReader API
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = () => {

    // use a regex to remove data url part
    const base64String = reader.result
        .replace('data:', '')
        .replace(/^.+,/, '');

    // log to console
    // logs wL2dvYWwgbW9yZ...
    console.log(base64String);
};
reader.readAsDataURL(file);});
```

Comment: [refer this](https://pqina.nl/blog/convert-a-file-to-a-base64-string-with-javascript/)

Answer (score 2):

I have used this simple method and it's worked successfully

```
 function  uploadImage(e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e) => {
    let image = e.target.result;
    console.log(image);
    };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
onInputChange(evt) {
    var tgt = evt.target || window.event.srcElement,
    files = tgt.files;
    if (FileReader && files && files.length) {
        var fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = function () {
            var base64 = fr.result;
            debugger;
        }
        fr.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert any file to base64 using this way -

```
_fileToBase64(file: File) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result.toString().substr(reader.result.toString().indexOf(',') + 1));
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This page is the first match when searching for how to convert a `file` object to a string. If you are not concerned about base64, the answer to that questions is as simple as:

```js
    str = await file.text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending on the above solutions by adding, with a use case where I required
the ability to iterate through multiple fields on a form and get their values
and with one being a file, it caused problems with he async requirements

Solved it like this:

```
    async collectFormData() {
        // Create the file parsing promise
        const toBase64 = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
            reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
        });
    
        
        let form_vals = []
        let els = [] // Form elements collection

        // This is separate because wrapping the await in a callback
        // doesn't work 
        $(`.form-field`).each(function (e) {
            els.push(this) // add to the collection of form fields
        })

        // Loop through the fields to collect information 
        for (let elKey in els) {
            let el = els[elKey]

            // If the field is input of type file. call the base64 parser
            if ($(el).attr('type') == 'file') {
                // Get a reference to the file
                const file = el.files[0];

                form_vals.push({
                    "key": el.id,
                    "value": await toBase64(file)
                })

        }


        // TODO: The rest of your code here form_vals will now be 
        // populated in time for a server post
    }
```

This is purely to solve the problem of dealing with multiple fields
in a smoother way

Answer (score 0):

```js
const file_to_base64 = async (a_file: File) => {
  let a_function = 
    (file: File) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => {
        let base64_string = String(reader.result).split(",")[1]
        resolve(base64_string)
      };
      reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
    })
    return (await a_function(a_file) as string)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This works

```js
// fileObj: File
const base64 = window.URL.createObjectURL(fileObj);

// You can use it with <img src={base64} />
```

Comment: This would provide you with a blob, not base64