# How to append file to axios post request

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios

Vue2.js + axios, can't append file to form data

```
axios.post( '/addTrack', this.form.data )
```

form data object:

```
        form: {
            data: {
                title : '',
                style : '',
                authors: [
                    {
                        id: '',
                        rightholder: 1,
                        percent: ''
                    }
                ],
                composers: [
                    {
                        id: '',
                        rightholder: 1,
                        percent: ''
                    }
                ],
                right_area: 1,
            },
            errors: {
            }
        },
```

How to add a file to this request? 
This doesn't work:

```
this.form.data.file = e.target.files[0];
```

console.log shows that form.data.file property is correct File object, but axios send this:

```
file:{_choosed: true}
```

Content-Type:application/json

Comment: You need to encode the file to be transmitted as part of the form. You can [encode it in base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280818/how-to-convert-file-to-base64-in-javascript), for example, and decode it server-side

Comment: Have you set any `Content-Type` in the headers?

Comment: by default Content-Type:application/json

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Umair, try setting the headers in the optional config parameter for the Axios post method as follows:

```
axios.post('/addTrack', this.form.data , {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
});
```

Comment: Warning: Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Ok, get rid of the header config value, then try this:

Create your form data like this:

`var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
 var formData = new FormData(myForm);`

Then add your file to the form data with the append method:

`formData.append(e.target.files[0]);`

Comment: It works! And there is no sense to append file because it already in myForm variable