# Convert Angular Material File Input to base64 format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design

I am using angular 1.7 with material design for my project. i am using angular material file input for this but it gives me result in file format. what i need is to convert that file format into base64 format. i have tried some external libraries but it doesn't work for me. can anyone post code or make a codepen/jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution (this is o copy of this post: [How to convert file to base64 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280818/how-to-convert-file-to-base64-in-javascript/36281449) ):

```
function getBase64(file) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   reader.onload = function () {
     console.log(reader.result);
   };
   reader.onerror = function (error) {
     console.log('Error: ', error);
   };
}

var file = /*Your file goes here*/
getBase64(file); // prints the base64 string
```

Comment: do you get a console output? the base64 - String is saved in the function in `reader.result` you have to return the value if you want to use it

Comment: can you show me how you set the file - Variable `var file = /*Your file goes here*/`

Comment: i selected the first file like var files = $scope.files[0]; and send this file to function getBase64(files);

Comment: what is the exception saying ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145791/discussion-between-matthias-gwiozda-and-zearaez).

Comment: Can you make a codepen or jsfiddle for this solution so that i can see how it works properly?