# Display PDF in Bootstrap File Input

Tags: jquery

I am using this Plugin For File Upload in JQuery:

http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input

While Uploading PDF File Preview is showing successfully but again when iam viewing file after upload it showing blank page for PDF File, but it showing Preview for Images.

```
var ticketFileAttahmentName= 'Karthik_B.TEch_Certificate2017-10-16 09:38:06.463.Karthik_B.TEch_Certificate.pdf';
var src="/atriticketing/files/" + ticketFileAttahmentName;
 $("#testing").fileinput({
            initialPreview: [src],
            initialPreviewAsData: true
         });
```

[After Viewing PDF File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48dq3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<iframe src=""></iframe>
```

Js ([answers to convert file to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280818/how-to-convert-file-to-base64-in-javascript)):

```
var base64File = getBase64File();
$('iframe').attr('src', base64File);
```