# Not able to insert the base64 data into the Word with Office Word add-in

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I am trying to insert file which is formatted as Base64 using `insertFileFromBase64()` but I am getting this exception:

```json
{
    "name": "OfficeExtension.Error",
    "code": "GeneralException",
    "message": "ooxmlIsMalformated",
    "traceMessages": [],
    "innerError": null,
    "debugInfo": {
        "code": "GeneralException",
        "message": "ooxmlIsMalformated",
        "errorLocation": "Body.insertFileFromBase64"
    }
}
```

My code is:

```js
// documentData - is a base64 string.
// Encoded base64 string = "V29yZCBEb2N1bWVudCBpcyBub3QgZ2V0IGluc2VydGVkIHVzaW5nIGluc2VydEZpbGVCYXNlNjQ="
body.insertFileFromBase64(documentData,window.Word.InsertLocation.replace);
```

I have tried other methods for HTML and text that are working, but getting the exception with `insertFileFromBase64`.

Can someone please guide me if I am missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/body#insertfilefrombase64base64file-string-insertlocation-string), the `base64File` parameter takes "The base64 encoded content of a .docx file."

The string your passing isn't an encoded `.docx`, it is simply an encoded string. The exception your getting is correct,  the OOXML you are passing *is* malformated (or more precisely, it isn't OOXML at all).

You will need to pass in a proper OOXML document that has been Base64 encoded for this method to work.

Comment: Thanks, @Marc LaFleur, 
Is there any way to convert OOMXL document into Base64 in Office js?
I tried to convert OOXML to base64 using javascript but yet no luck...

Comment: Base64 is just an encoding. You would encode it just as you would any other file type. This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280818/how-to-convert-file-to-base64-in-javascript