# Error while using fs.readFileSync

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to convert an uploaded image to base 64

```
       var file = e.target.files[0];
       var imageFile = fs.readFileSync(file);
       var encoded = new Buffer(imageFile).toString('base64');
```

I get an error saying :

TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_fs___default.a.readFileSync is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mention of `__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_fs___` and the use of `e.target.files` suggests you are not running this code under Node.js but are bundling it up with WebPack and trying to run it in the browser.

The fs module requires Node.js.

You need to find a different approach if you want to do this in a browser.

See [How to convert file to base64 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280818/how-to-convert-file-to-base64-in-javascript).