# How to upload a JPG on to AWS Lambda (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, aws-lambda

I am trying to do this:

1. Frontend: set up file to upload using `<input type="file">` and `<input type="button" onClick="...">`
2. The File Object is retrieved using `file[0]` from the `<input type="file">`'s value.
3. Use Javascript `Fetch` api to call on my AWS API-Gateway `Post` API.

**I have tried both `multipart/form-data` and `application/json` in the request.**

4. On the AWS Lambda, I have used Buffer Object to consume the body.

**I have tried using `Buffer(body, "utf8")`, `Buffer(body, "base64")`, `Buffer(body, "binary")`.**

5. This is, in turn, pushed up to `S3` for storage using `putObject`.

**Problem:**

- The file object that was set up in `S3` has either filesize 0 or some random value that's not matching the original filesize.
- The file downloaded from `S3` cannot be opened.

**Failed Approaches**

I have considered `multer` and `multiparty`. These seem to be `ExpressJS` middleware and expects a `HttpRequest` object as input (this wasn't mentioned explicitly. It seems like I am ignorant enough not to assume that these can only work with `HttpRequest` object and it took me a while to find out). I am also ignorant enough not to know how to transform an AWS event object into a HttpRequest object. But that said, it seems excessive to use Express engine just for the sake of managing file upload.

Exposing my `S3` bucket as `public-read-write` seems to be rather insecure. So I am not considering the frontend directly moving stuff in/out of my `S3` bucket.

**My Request**

Can anyone tell me how to get this to work? And/or an alternative to this approach?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

**Frontend**

- Specifically encoding `File` Object to `base64` string. ([How to convert file to base64 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280818/how-to-convert-file-to-base64-in-javascript))
- Examining the encoded string-date of the file, you will find that it has **a `;` delimited header**. This is also not explicitly mentioned anywhere. Use `.split()` and `.join()` to remove the header.
- Now you can compose your request in whatever form you want. I took the easy way out and used JSON.
- Here's some code that do what I have mentioned:

  ```
  const getBase64fromFile = (file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => {
        console.log(`getBase64fromFile success.`);
        const spliced = reader.result.split(',');
        const header = spliced[0];
        spliced.shift();
        resolve({
          header: header,
          body: spliced.join('')
        });
      };
      reader.onerror = (err) => {
        console.log(`getBase64fromFile failed.`);
        reject(err);
      };
    });
  }

  uploadHandler() { 
    console.log(this.state.selectedFile);

  const selectedFile = this.state.selectedFile;
  const email = this.state.email;
  return getBase64fromFile(selectedFile)
  .then((base64Data) => {
    return {
      name: selectedFile.name,
      header: base64Data.header,
      base64: base64Data.body,
      email: email
    }
  })
  .then((body) => {
    console.log(`${JSON.stringify(body)}`);
    return body;
  })
  .then((body) => {
    this.setState({status: "Begin uploading..."});
    return fetch(this.state.url+"/upload",
    { // Your POST endpoint
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + this.state.token,
        "x-api-key": this.state.apikey,
        "Accept": "application/json",
      }, 
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    });
  })
  .then(
    response => response.json() // if the response is a JSON object
  )
  .then(
    success => {
      console.log(success); // Handle the success response object
      this.setState({
        status: success.message
      });
    }
  )
  .catch(
    error => {console.log(error) ;// Handle the error response object
      this.setState({
        status: JSON.stringify(error)
      });
    })
  ;
  }
  ```

(https://github.com/flameoftheforest/yaUserMan/blob/master/Tests/frontend/src/App.js)

**AWS-Lambda**

- Now we know that the data is coming in as a base64 string, convert it to octet using `Buffer.from(body, "base64")`.
- The output of `Buffer.from()` is the `<binary string>` that `putObject` requires.
- Here's some code that does what I have mentioned:

  ```
  const params = {
    Bucket: process.env.IMAGE_BUCKET,
    Key: uuid() + event.body.name,
    Body: Buffer.from(event.body.base64, 'base64'),
    ACL: "public-read"
  };
  ```

(https://github.com/flameoftheforest/yaUserMan/blob/master/yaUserMan/file2S3Helper.js)

Ref: https://medium.com/@olotintemitope/how-to-upload-files-to-amazon-s3-using-nodejs-lambda-and-api-gateway-bae665127907