# Error trying to upload an image with js, jquery and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dom

How I said in the title I am trying to upload an image with js/jquery but I do not know how to take the image to send it to server (PHP).
I have a form with all the information that I want and then with jquery i take all this information to save it in MySql.
I tried to get an object with the image attributes but got this error:

I am doing something wrong or maybe I need something else...?

Sorry for my bad English.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is almost certainly caused by your data not being in the correct format...`jsonp` in this case.

Comment: Try `data: formData,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do that is by using the following [plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) that allows you to have some upload progressbar as well (in case you boss needs more ui).

An another approach is to read the file's contents as seen in this [link](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/), and convert it as base64 as seen in this [question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280818/how-to-convert-file-to-base64-in-javascript) answers.

An another approach is by looking this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28024824/4706711) as well.