# Trying to change the value of Input using Javascrpit getting security error

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to resize a user input using Javascript. I am able to get right to almost the last part.

1. I am taking  the user input image
2. I am creating a new image with the same src as the input image
3. I am resizing the new image
4. I show a small preview thumbnail to the user
5. SO far everything worked... Now the last part that did not work
6. I change the input.result = new_resized_image.src

Below is the error message I get

[image]

Below is the code

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");

        const file_input = document.getElementById('main_image');
        file_input.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        const file = file_input.files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function () {
            if (!file.name.match(/.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/i)){
                alert('Only jpg, jpeg, png, gif accepted at the moment');
                file_input.value = "";
            }
            if (file.size <= (1024*1024)){
                const img = new Image();
                img.src = reader.result;
                console.log("Small Image Width " + img.width);
                console.log( "Small Image Height " + img.height);
                const preview_image = document.getElementById("preview");
                preview_image.src = img.src;
                console.log("Thumbnail Image height " + preview_image.height);
                console.log("Thumbnail Image width " + preview_image.width);
            }
            else {
                const img = new Image();
                img.src = reader.result;
                const preview_image = document.getElementById("preview");
                const MAX_WIDTH = 1024;
                const MAX_HEIGHT = 1024;

                img.onload = function(){
                    console.log(img.width);
                    console.log(img.height);
                    let width = img.width;
                    let height = img.height;

                    if (width > height){
                        if (width > MAX_WIDTH){
                            height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                            width = MAX_WIDTH;
                        }
                    }else {
                        if (height > MAX_HEIGHT){
                            width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                            height = MAX_HEIGHT
                        }
                    }
                    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                    canvas.width = width;
                    canvas.height = height;
                    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
                    const new_image = document.getElementById("new_image");
                    new_image.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
                    new_image.onload = function(){
                      console.log(this.width);
                      console.log(this.height);
                    };


                    preview_image.src = new_image.src;
                    file_input.value = new_image.src;

                };
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)

Comment: @AlexisWilke Do you think there is a possible workaround

Comment: It is possible to convert the data to base64 and stick that in a hidden `<input>` or `<textarea>` if what you want is to send the image back to the server when the client submits the form. I'm not too sure how useful that is, though. Then you can fake the "Browse" button to look like a more or less standard browse button if you think that's important.

Comment: @AlexisWilke you think you could post that in a answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always possible to convert the data to [base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280818/how-to-convert-file-to-base64-in-javascript) and stick that in a hidden `<input>` or `<textarea>` if what you want is to send the image back to the server when the client submits *the form*.

Then you can always have a button that looks like a "Browse" button if you think that's important to have such in your form.

Also, you could use [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to send the `base64` or some other type of data to your server.

Answer (score 0):

I think the last line should be

`file_input.src` instead of `file_input.value`

Comment: that didn't change the image. It just shows the unsized image