# I have encryption working for text files; how to do it for any type of file?

Tags: javascript

**Question:**

How can I encrypt and decrypt any type of file using Javascript? Is there any libraries to do encryption that I could include?

My problem is I need to encrypt and decrypt any type of file in a browser, but my code is working only for text. I need a code to encrypt and decrypt any type of file.

**Current situation:**

The below code works fine when I use it with text files but does not work with any other file type:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <script src = "F:\GitHub\sample\example\script\forge.all.min.js"></script>
                <script src = "F:\GitHub\sample\example\script\forge.min.js"></script>
            </head>
        <body onload="myFunction()"> 

        <input type="file" id="myFile" multiple size="50" onchange="myFunction()">

        <p id="demo"></p>

        <script>
        function myFunction(){
          var x = document.getElementById("myFile");
          var txt = "";
          var file = x.files[0];
          var filename = file.name;

        var key = forge.random.getBytesSync(16);
        var iv = forge.random.getBytesSync(8);
        var cipher = forge.rc2.createEncryptionCipher(key);
        cipher.start(iv);
        cipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer());
        cipher.finish();
        var encrypted = cipher.output;
        console.log(encrypted);
        console.log(encrypted.toHex());
        var cipher = forge.rc2.createDecryptionCipher(key);
        cipher.start(iv);
        cipher.update(encrypted);
        cipher.finish();
        console.log(cipher.output);
        console.log(cipher.output.toHex());
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = encrypted;
        }
        </script>

        <p><strong>Tip:</strong> Use the Control or the Shift key to select multiple files.</p>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: [Convert files to Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280818/how-to-convert-file-to-base64-in-javascript) and encrypt the base64 string.

Comment: moved question to the start of the phrase and added titles

Comment: I have already tried with base64 string but It also works for only string.