# Ajax Upload file / image

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

Is it possible to incorporate an image upload to this ajax form? This form is working already, just this `file:file.val();` section that is new.

```
 <div class="input-group">
                          <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupFileAddon01">Upload</span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="custom-file">

                            <input name="file" type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="file" id="file"
                              aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01">
                            <label class="custom-file-label" for="file">Choose Thumbnail</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

Here is the function I use for the form right now. Again, this works. Just not sure how to incorporate the file upload.
I can figure that PHP that is required on the action.php page. I just don't know how to get it past this ajax query.

```
function manageData(key) {

var client_id = $("#client_id");
var listing_number = $("#listing_number");
var price = $("#price");
var address = $("#address");
var address_2 = $("#address_2");
var city = $("#city");
var state = $("#state");
var zip = $("#zip");
var bd = $("#bd");
var ba = $("#ba");
var lot_sq = $("#lot_sq");
var abvgrd = $("#abvgrd");
var yr = $("#yr");
var type = $("#type");
var status = $("#status");
var link = $("#link");
var remarks = $("#remarks");
var file = $("#file");
var editRowID = $("#editRowID");


$.ajax({
   url: 'action.php',
   method: 'POST',
   dataType: 'text',
   data: {

        key: key,
        client_id: client_id.val(),
        listing_number: listing_number.val(),
        price: price.val(),
        address: address.val(),
        address_2: address_2.val(),
        city: city.val(),
        state: state.val(),
        zip: zip.val(),
        bd: bd.val(),
        ba: ba.val(),
        lot_sq: lot_sq.val(),
        abvgrd: abvgrd.val(),
        yr: yr.val(),
        type: type.val(),
        status: status.val(),
        link: link.val(),
        remarks: remarks.val(),
        file: file.val(),
        rowID: editRowID.val()

   }, success: function (response) {
        if (response != "success")
            alert(response);
        else {
            client_id.val(' ');
            listing_number.val(' ');
            price.val(' ');
            address.val(' ');
            address_2.val(' ');
            city.val(' ');
            state.val(' ');
            zip.val(' ');
            bd.val(' ');
            ba.val(' ');
            lot_sq.val(' ');
            abvgrd.val(' ');
            yr.val(' ');
            type.val(' ');
            status.val(' ');
            link.val(' ');
            remarks.val(' ');
            //file.val(' ');
            $("#tableManager").modal('hide');
            $("#manageBtn").attr('value', 'Add').attr('onclick', "manageData('addNew')");
        }
   }
});
```

}

Comment: @Rory McCrossan This is not a duplicate... I am asking if it is possible with my current AJAX setup, not changing everything up.

Comment: Not using FormData

Comment: Technically you could convert the file to base64 and then upload that via AJAX, although it's not the best idea. FormData by far the most ideal solution to this.

Comment: See this question for details on how to convert the file to a Base64 string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280818/how-to-convert-file-to-base64-in-javascript.