# Get base64 content from local mp3/mp4

Tags: javascript, audio, base64, mp4

I'm trying to get the base64 content from a local audio on my device using javascript.
I'm using the following code:

```
var file = new File(["file_name.mp4"], "/data/user/files/VoiceRecordingPluginData/file_name.mp4");
var reader = new FileReader();

// Read file content on file loaded event
reader.onloadend = function (event) {
    console.log(reader.result);
};

// Convert data to base64
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

As result, "file" gets populated like this:
file.name: ["file_name.mp4"]
file.localURL: "/data/user/files/VoiceRecordingPluginData/file_name.mp4"

Once "onloaded" is reached, "reader.result" is empty.

Any hints on what's wrong in my code?

Comment: Hello. Can you explain the application? The HTML5 `file` class expects *user* input not hard coded. You cant arbitrarily access files without "permission" on the user's file system I dont think, even your own.

Comment: check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280818/how-to-convert-file-to-base64-in-javascript

Comment: You can't read a data file from a client's computer like that, nor read a file from a server like that. To read client file you need some type of user interaction like selecting a file in a input file element or drag&drop operation. For server you would need to use ajax

Comment: I'm using the Cordova voice recording plugin to build an Android app (WebView). 
As a result of that plugin interaction, we get an audio that's located on a particular path. I'm new to the javascript world,  so my aproach using File and FileReader is wrong then, as i guess from your reply...