# Upload file is only sending text to e-mail from React Form

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, forms, file-upload

So I am trying to send data that is inputted from a form in React to an e-mail address.

Everything is working perfectly, except where I try and upload a file and it only sends the text of the path file to the e-mail.

---

eg, the email will look like this:

From: test

Email: testing@gmail.com

Message: testing

File: C:\fakepath\2020-06-10 18-49-37.mp4

---

I obviously don't want the text to show up on the e-mail, but a file to be uploaded instead.

Any ideas on how to make this work.

I will post heaps of code below for everyone to check out.

Thanks in advance!

**Form.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import Axios from 'axios'


class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      message: '',
      file: null,
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState(
      {
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        [event.target.email]: event.target.value,
        [event.target.message]: event.target.value,
        [event.target.file]: event.target.file,
      }
    );
  }

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    })

  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log(this.state)
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = {
      name: this.state.name,
      email: this.state.email,
      message: this.state.message,
      file: this.state.file,
    };

    Axios.post("api/v1/sendMail", data)
      {
      alert("Thank you! We will be in touch shortly!")
      }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="formContainer centerImg" id="formScale">
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} method="post">
            <div className='contact'>
              <h2 className="formTitles">YOUR FULL NAME</h2>
              <input
                name='name'
                value={this.state.name}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                required />
              <h2 className="formTitles">EMAIL ADDRESS</h2>
              <input
                name='email'
                value={this.state.email}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                required />
              <h2 className="formTitles">UPLOAD FILE</h2>
              <input
                type='file'
                name='file'
                value={this.state.file}
                onChange={this.handleChange} />
              <div id='messageForm'>
                <h2 className="formTitles">MESSAGE</h2>
                <textarea
                  name='message'
                  value={this.state.message}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  required />
              </div>                      
              <div id='submit-btn'>
                <input type='submit' value='SUBMIT' />
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default Form
```

**(server) index.js**

```
const server = require('./server')

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(cookieParser());

const { sendEmail } = require("../server/routes/mail");

server.post("/api/v1/sendMail", (req, res) => {
  sendEmail(req.body.name, req.body.email, req.body.message, req.body.file);
});

const port = 3000

server.listen(port, () => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log('Server listening on port', port)
})
```

**mail.js**

```
const mailer = require("nodemailer");

const getEmailData = (name, email, message, file) => {
    let data = null;


            data = {
                from: "Contact Form",
                to: "(*correct e-mail here*)",
                subject: `Message from the contact form!`,
                html: `<b>From:</b>&nbsp;${name}
                      <br><br><b>Email:</b>&nbsp;${email}
                      <br><br><b>Message:</b>&nbsp;${message}
                      <br><br><b>File:</b>&nbsp;${file}`
            }
    return data;
}


    const sendEmail = (name, email, message, file) => {

        const smtpTransport = mailer.createTransport({
            service: "Gmail",
            auth: {
                user: "(correct e-mail here)",
                pass: "(correct password here)"
            }
        })

        const mail = getEmailData(name, email, message, file)

        smtpTransport.sendMail(mail, function(error, response) {
            if(error) {
                console.log(error)
            } else {
                alert( "Thank you! We will be in touch shortly!")
            }
            smtpTransport.close();
        })


    }

    module.exports = { sendEmail }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Józef Podlecki provided guidance to get the right solution, this is the final code to anyone who is trying to get the final solution to work.

**Form.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import Axios from 'axios'

const toBase64 = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
  reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
});

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      message: '',
      file: null,

    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleFileChange = this.handleFileChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleFileChange({target: {name, files}}) {
    toBase64(files[0]).then(dataUri => {
      this.setState(state => ({...state, [name]: dataUri}))
    })
 }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState(
      {
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        [event.target.email]: event.target.value,
        [event.target.message]: event.target.value,
      }
    );
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = {...this.state};

    Axios.post("api/v1/sendMail", data)
      {
      alert("Thank you! We will be in touch shortly!")
      }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="formContainer centerImg" id="formScale">
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} method="post">
            <div className='contact'>
              <h2 className="formTitles">YOUR FULL NAME</h2>
              <input
                name='name'
                value={this.state.name}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                required />
              <h2 className="formTitles">EMAIL ADDRESS</h2>
              <input
                name='email'
                value={this.state.email}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                required />
              <h2 className="formTitles">UPLOAD FILE</h2>
              <input
                type='file'
                name='file'
                // value={this.state.file}
                onChange={this.handleFileChange} />
              <div id='messageForm'>
                <h2 className="formTitles">MESSAGE</h2>
                <textarea
                  name='message'
                  value={this.state.message}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  required />
              </div>
              <div id='submit-btn'>
                <input type='submit' value='SUBMIT' />
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default Form
```

**(server) index.js**

```
const server = require('./server')
const express = require('express')

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

server.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}))
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(cookieParser());

const { sendEmail } = require("../server/routes/mail");



server.post("/api/v1/sendMail", (req, res) => {
  sendEmail(req.body.name, req.body.email, req.body.message, req.body.file);
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, () => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log('Server listening on port', port)
})
```

**mail.js**

```
const mailer = require("nodemailer");

const getEmailData = (name, email, message, file) => {
    let data = null;


        data = {
            from: "Contact Form",
            to: "(correct e-mail here)",
            subject: `Message from the contact form!`,
            attachments: [
                {
                  path: `${file}`
                }
              ],
            html: `<b>From:</b>&nbsp;${name}
                  <br><br><b>Email:</b>&nbsp;${email}
                  <br><br><b>Message:</b>&nbsp;${message}`
            }
    return data;
}


    const sendEmail = (name, email, message, file) => {

        const smtpTransport = mailer.createTransport({
            service: "Gmail",
            auth: {
                user: "(correct e-mail here)",
                pass: "(correct password here)"
            }
        })

        const mail = getEmailData(name, email, message, file)

        smtpTransport.sendMail(mail, function(error, response) {
            if(error) {
                console.log(error)
            } else {
                alert( "Thank you! We will be in touch shortly!")
            }
            smtpTransport.close();
        })


    }

    module.exports = { sendEmail }
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you send a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) and parse the FormData on the server.

For express servers you can use [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) to parse the request.

send the form data on the client side:

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("name", this.state.name);
formData.append("email", this.state.email);
formData.append("message", this.state.message);
formData.append("file", this.state.file);
Axios.post("api/v1/sendMail", formData);
```

on server side, use the `directUpload` middleware and `console.log(req.files)` in your request handler:

```js
const upload = multer({
  storage: multer.memoryStorage()
});
const directUpload = upload.fields([{
  name: "name"
}, {
  name: "email"
}, {
  name: "message"
}, {
  name: "file"
}]);

server.post("/api/v1/sendMail", directUpload, (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.files);
  sendEmail(req.body.name, req.body.email, req.body.message, req.body.file);
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it with the way I am coding it at the moment? I am only a junior so I wouldn't know how to translate anything I have done into a FormData format.

Comment: Thanks ardean, would that go on my mail or index server file?

Comment: You can use the middleware before your mail handler, like I did in the answer.

Comment: Did it and it doesn't work. With all that code it just comes up exactly the same. Text and no file.

Answer (score 2):

You can either send [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) or [convert file to dataUri and handle it on the backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280818/how-to-convert-file-to-base64-in-javascript)

**Form Data**

```js
handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // or you can set ref to form and use new FormData(formRef.current)
  // but then keeping state doesnt make sense at all
  const formData = new FormData();
  for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(this.state)) {
    formData.append(key, value);
  }


  Axios.post("api/v1/sendMail", formData)
      {
      alert("Thank you! We will be in touch shortly!")
      }
  }
```

```
handleFileChange({target: {name, files}}) {
   this.setState(state => ({...state, [name]: files[0]}))
}
```

```
 <input
  type='file'
  name='file'
  onChange={this.handleFileChange} />
```

**Data Uri**

```js
const toBase64 = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
});

 handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = {...this.state};

    Axios.post("api/v1/sendMail", data)
      {
      alert("Thank you! We will be in touch shortly!")
      }
  }

handleFileChange({target: {name, files}}) {
   toBase64(files[0]).then(dataUri => {
     this.setState(state => ({...state, [name]: dataUri}))
   })
}
```

```
<input
  type='file'
  name='file'
  onChange={this.handleFileChange} />
```

Also this can be simplified

```js
handleChange({target: {name, value}}) {
    this.setState(state => ({...state, [name]: value}))
}
```

**Example**

```js
const { Component, Fragment, createRef } = React;

const toBase64 = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
});

class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      variant1: {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        message: '',
        file: null,
      },
      variant2: {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        message: '',
        file: null
      }        
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit1 = this.handleSubmit1.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit2 = this.handleSubmit2.bind(this);
    this.handleFileChange1 = this.handleFileChange1.bind(this);
    this.handleFileChange2 = this.handleFileChange2.bind(this);
    this.formRef = createRef(null);
  }
  
  handleFileChange1({target: {name, files}}) {
    toBase64(files[0]).then(dataUri => {
      this.setState(state => ({
        ...state,
        variant1: {
          ...state.variant1,
          [name]: dataUri
        }
      }))
    })
  }
  
  handleFileChange2({target: {name, files}}) {
    this.setState(state => ({
      ...state,
      variant2: {
        ...state.variant2,
        [name]: files[0]
      }
    }))
  }

  handleChange({target: {name, value}}) {
    this.setState(state => ({
      ...state,
      variant1: {
        ...state.variant1,
        [name]: value
      },
      variant2: {
        ...state.variant2,
        [name]: value
      }
    }))
  }

  handleSubmit1(event) {
    const data = {...this.state.variant1}
    console.log('json', data);
  }
  
  handleSubmit2(event) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(this.state.variant2)) {
      formData.append(key, value);
    }
    console.log('form data', [...formData.entries()]);
    
    const formData1 = new FormData(this.formRef.current);
    console.log('formdata ref', [...formData1.entries()]);
  }

  render() {
    const { name, email, message } = this.state.variant1;
    
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="formContainer centerImg" id="formScale">
          <form ref={this.formRef} onSubmit={(event) => {event.preventDefault();this.handleSubmit1(event);this.handleSubmit2(event)}} method="post">
            <div className='contact'>
              <h2 className="formTitles">YOUR FULL NAME</h2>
              <input
                name='name'
                value={name}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                required />
              <h2 className="formTitles">EMAIL ADDRESS</h2>
              <input
                name='email'
                value={email}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                required />
              <h2 className="formTitles">UPLOAD FILE</h2>
              <input
                type='file'
                name='file'
                onChange={(event) => {this.handleFileChange1(event);this.handleFileChange2(event)}} />
              <div id='messageForm'>
                <h2 className="formTitles">MESSAGE</h2>
                <textarea
                  name='message'
                  value={message}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  required />
              </div>                      
              <div id='submit-btn'>
                <input type='submit' value='SUBMIT' />
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Form />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Updated answer. Here are two solutions

Comment: copied the code, it didn't work. it all comes up with undefined.

Comment: Which solution did you choose? Did you bind `handleFileChange`? What does the `console log(this.state)` or `console log([...formData.entries()])` show?

Comment: I tried both, neither worked at all. It either just came up with the pathfile again as text or came up as undefined. I did bind handleFileChange as well. Console log either shows undefined or just text of what's being inputted from the form.

Comment: Added snippet with three mentioned cases.

Comment: Alright so, using the first one (handlesubmit1, handlefilechange1, etc), I get an e-mail with just json data basically as text.

Comment: Using the second variant, everything comes up as undefined.

Comment: Check in browser networking tab if axios is sending requests with specific content type and formatted payload for each type. This is backend issue. axios probably required additional  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'  header

Comment: I've been troubleshooting this over the last couple of days to no avail. All I can get is just a whole lot of json data in the body at best. I can console log the file up until the point before I set the state and everything is fine, and then it all just doesn't work.

I put the site live to see if it was a development issue and then I got 503 errors on Heroku.

Comment: Did you check in networking tab if request has required content type and form-data?

Comment: Can you set `app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));` ? Or if you are using form data `app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '50mb'}));`

Comment: in the network tab it shows:

file: data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4gv4SUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQE...

after the ... is just a whole lot of json data I assume.

Comment: I am using the base64 way as well

Comment: do I set that on my index.js? If so it doesn't do anything.

Comment: So I managed to get it working.

I used all the Data Uri examples, had to put the limit as 50mb, although I had to put the file as an attachment with nodemailer syntax in my mail.js file which looked like:                 attachments: [ {path:
 `${file}`
 },
Thanks for your help :)