# How to return Base64 which I can use with <img src="renderedImg(photo)"/>

Tags: javascript, image, file, base64

I did not found answer. The same problem is [How to convert file to base64 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280818/how-to-convert-file-to-base64-in-javascript).

```
previewPhoto (photo, id) {
  const preview = document.getElementById(id)
  const reader = new FileReader()

  reader.onloadend = function () {
    preview.src = reader.result
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(photo)
},
```

There I just replace the src value in element by querySelector. But in may case I need something like this:

```
previewPhoto (photo) {
  const readyToSrcImg = fileToImg(photo)

  return readyToSrcImg
},
```

Does anyone know about this case?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the FileReader to preview a image as base64 - it waste time to encode/decode and uses more memory - meaning: it's slower.

Use `URL.createObjectURL(file)` to create a references link to the raw binary instead

```js
previewPhoto (photo, id) {
  const preview = document.getElementById(id)
  preview.src = URL.createObjectURL(photo)
},
```