# How to include an other file in a JSON file?

Tags: json, file

The API's Documentation said I should put in Body Params:

1. restaurant_token:(required)string -> API Access Token provided by Tiller
2. provider_token:(required)string -> API Access Token provided by Tiller
3. inventory:(required)file -> Inventory import file
4. clear:(booleantrue) -> remove existing items or not

My POST request is :

https://app.tillersystems.com/api/inventory/import

And my JSON is:

```json
{
    "provider_token": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "restaurant_token": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "inventory": "C://Mes Projets//N74_Interface_Sage_Tiller//Exe//Traitement//Articles_SAGE_20210826172848541.csv",
    "clear": true
}
```

The request's answer is:

```json
{
    "import": false,
    "message": "Missing \"inventory\" file field."
}
```

Comment: You can convert the file to base64. But do not forget that in this case, its size increases by 33%

Answer (score 0):

You can encode file to **base64** and put it as string like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57272491/16593275)

But I think the best solution is to **use standard file sharing protocols**

To send large files, in any case, you will have to send them in their original form, without conversion to base64.

To download files on the client, you can receive data about the file in the json format, which will include the generated link to download the file using the standard protocol.