# Office Word How can get docunet as file

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

In my plugin i try to get open file as byte array or base64 so i can send via API, is there any way to make that with Word-Js, also is there any way to return document size and name and meta data?

search in

```
 context.document.properties 
 Office.context.document.settings
```

but no result as expected

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert file to base64 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280818/how-to-convert-file-to-base64-in-javascript)

Comment: Also, this might help: [Get the whole document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/get-the-whole-document-from-an-add-in-for-word)

Comment: @RickKirkham thank you that exactly what i am looking for, do you know how get the document name

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document?view=common-js-preview#office-office-document-getfilepropertiesasync-member(1) 

getFileProperties API will get the url of your file which contains the file name.